# How can I call web services from a database driver?

Tags: java, database, web-services, odbc, dsn

I have a COTS (commercial, off the shelf) application that must connect to some kind of ODBC connection (the driver doesn't really matter). However rather than save to a database, I want the data to be saved via an HTTP Post to a webservice. Is there any way to link a database driver to a web service? Am I stuck with writing my own database driver?

Comment: The only solution I've come up with so far is having a local database anyway, but a separate process that queries the database from time-to-time and uses the data in the database to post to the web service. I'd like something a little more elegant and streamlined though...

Comment: I would imagine writing an ODBC driver is complex. Would likely be easier to do your own suggestion. Pump the data to a database and use triggers to send data to the web service. Both SQL Server and MySQL allow for triggers that can run arbitrary code. Unwise to do this in general, but possible for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the comment ryan1234. I hadn't thought of using a trigger within the database... That might actually be cleaner (and less coding) than having a separate process that polls the database.